# Flash AS3 Camera to show the same movement

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am a newbie in Flash ActionScript.

I am trying to capture an image using webcam via Flash. I managed to do this but I have encountered a problem in which:

1. When I moved my head to the right, the video in Flash is showing that my head is moving on the opposite direction.

I guess to be clearer:

1. Try on Facebook.com and click "add photos/videos" on the status update.
2. Click on "Use Webcam" and allow webcam.
3. You'll notice that when it is in "video" mode, when you move your head to the right, the screen will show that your head is moving in the opposite direction.
4. Now, click on the icon on the top right to switch to "photo" mode. Now, when you move your head to the right, the screen will show that your head is moving to the right as well!

Thus, I wonder what I should do / edit so that #4 is the one that happens.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how to do this:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.geom.Matrix;

    public class main extends Sprite {
        private var cam:Camera;
        private var vid:Video;

        public function main() {

            cam = Camera.getCamera(); 
            if (!cam) {
                trace("No camera is installed.");
            }else {
                connectCamera();
            }
        }

        private function connectCamera():void {
            vid = new Video();
            vid.width = cam.width;
            vid.height = cam.height; 
            vid.attachCamera(cam);

            var WIDTH:int=vid.width
            var ma:Matrix=new Matrix();
            ma.a=-1;
            ma.tx=WIDTH;
            vid.transform.matrix= ma;
            vid.x = vid.x - vid.width;

            addChild(vid);
        }
    }
}
```